# Search folders to a certain depth, so not to return every subfolder

Tags: vb.net

I have a simple button which when clicked populates a listbox of all subfolders which is contained in a textbox.  Is it possible to carry out the search so it only returns a certain depth/level of subfolders.

For example, instead of:

folder1>subfolder1>subfolder2>subfolder3>subfolder4

I can tell it to just return the first 2 levels:
folder1>subfolder1>subfolder2>

My current code is as follows

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    AddFolders(txtsearchdirectory.Text)
End Sub
Private Sub AddFolders(root As String)
    ListBox1.Items.Add(root)
    Try
        For Each folder As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectories(root)
            AddFolders(folder)
            Application.DoEvents()
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `Application.DoEvents()` in this context? Generally speaking, you do not want to pump the message queue like that.

Comment: Lots of copy-paste cargo-cult code here. `DoEvents` is the real problem, but a catch block that swallows all exceptions is also a bad idea. You do not need to handle exceptions to get a message box. That happens automatically for unhandled exceptions. Only handle exceptions that you can actually...well, handle. And don't use `DoEvents`. It is not a magic "keep my UI responsive" function. This code should not take long enough that it is necessary to run it on a background thread. I can iterate the entire file system on my machine in the time it takes a user's brain to process a "click" event.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this when working with a heavily populated tree view. I've tested it and it seems to do what you are asking for. If you want a variable maximum just add another parameter and pass it down the chain.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    AddFolders(txtsearchdirectory.Text, 0)
End Sub

Private Sub AddFolders(root As String, recursionDepth As Integer)
    If recursionDepth <= 2 Then
        ListBox1.Items.Add(root)
        Try
            For Each folder As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectories(root)
                AddFolders(folder, recursionDepth + 1)
                Application.DoEvents()
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I didn't add it, so you're better off asking OP

Comment: You could make it cleaner by using `If recursionDepth > 0 Then...`, `AddFolders(folder, recursionDepth - 1)`, and calling it with `AddFolders(txtsearchdirectory.Text, 2)`. There may be an off-by-one error in there.